# how to export data from react bootstrap table without getting objects

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am using the react bootstrap table for grid view. In that I am using `exportCSV={true}` for export data. I am getting exported data as `[Object]`.

In below  I provide the code and Example data. Please check and help me to get proper data and column names in exported data.

**React Code :**

```
                  <BootstrapTable
                    data={this.state.auditActivityData}
                    version="4"
                    striped
                    hover
                    pagination
                    search
                    exportCSV={true}
                    options={DatatableOptions}
                  >
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                      dataField="comment_images"
                      dataFormat={this.fileHandle.bind(this)}
                      dataSort
                      width="75"
                    >
                      Files
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                      isKey
                      dataField="auditId"
                      dataFormat={this.auditdata.bind(this)}
                      dataSort
                    >
                      Audit Name
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                      dataField="assetId"
                      dataFormat={this.AssetName.bind(this)}
                      dataSort
                    >
                      Asset Name
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                      dataField="assetId"
                      dataFormat={this.assetcode.bind(this)}
                    >
                      asset Code
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                      dataField="comment"
                      // dataFormat={this.AssetStatus.bind(this)}
                    >
                      Comments
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                      dataField="commentedBy"
                      dataFormat={this.auditedBy.bind(this)}
                    >
                      Auditor
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                      dataField="assetAvailability"
                      dataFormat={this.assetAvailability.bind(this)}
                      thStyle={{ whiteSpace: "normal" }}
                    >
                      Asset Availability
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn
                      dataField="assetCodition"
                      dataFormat={this.AssetCondition.bind(this)}
                      thStyle={{ whiteSpace: "normal" }}
                    >
                      Asset Condition
                    </TableHeaderColumn>
```

**Example data :**
[In this link you can find the example data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3qs5.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`csvFormat`](https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#csvFormat) to convert your object to a string, the same way you use `dataFormat`.